# EPERM Error!! Is there any way I can resolve my React Installation issues?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, installation, npx

Below is the error message:

> ```
> An unexpected error occurred: '*EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'F:\\N Programs\\my-react-app\\node_modules\\@babel\\helper-create-class-features-plugin\\node_modules\\@babel\\core\\node_modules\\.bin'".pkg...
> npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTYe platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
> npm ERR! syscall rmdiris an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\6868\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\tmp\node_modules
> npm ERR! errno -40513" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
> npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\6868\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\tmp\node_modules'
> warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev ||
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-07T13_47_19_223Z-debug.log/dom@>=7.21.4
> ```

I have tried `npm cache clean --force` command.

In addition with this I have also tried to clear cookies manually inside the npm-cache folder.

Also tried installation inside the administrator mode using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Re-installation of node has also been tried several times. But the below error is still there:

> ```
> '*EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'F:\\N Programs\\my-react-app\\node_modules\\@babel\\helper-create-class-features-plugin\\node_modules\\@babel\\core\\node_modules\\.bin'".pkg...*'
> ```

I think the main problem is the cache are fetching from C drive that is why its not working properly. I installed and run the first todo app on the desktop this is why the path is set into C drive but now I am working with F drive and it worked for 1 or 2 projects but now I am in a big trouble.

Comment: I'll give you a tip. When asking a question that involves pasting logs and code snippets here, wrap them around ``` quotes

Comment: This looks like an IO error, try restarting your computer